# how to move cursor left and right in a router's busybox shell

Tags: shell, busybox, apple, ash

my router runs asuswrt merlin.  the /bin/sh is packaged in BusyBox v1.25.1 (2017-12-02 00:49:46 EST) multi-call binary.

my question is how do I move my cursor one word left and right?

with bash, i can do `option+left`, `option+right`, which is mapped in terminal to `\033b` and `\033f` respectively.

on my router's shell, it just prints a `b` and an `f`.  so how do i remap shortcuts in shell or what out of the (busy)box shortcut is there?

Note 1: i found that `busybox` supposedly packages `ash` shell, so my question may be how to move cursor one word with `ash` shell.

Note 2: i tried enabling and disabling the following option to use meta+b and meta+f, no luck

[image: using option as meta key]

Note 3: added apple and ash tags

Comment: So when you say `option+left` you are on a Apple computer? If so, you may want to add Apple tag.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> will move the cursor forward and back word by word, respectively.

If you're on a terminal or connection chain that does not properly pass the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key along for the ride, as appears to be your case, <kbd>Esc</kbd> is a signal that the next character sent it meant to be a keystroke altered by <kbd>Meta</kbd>.  So:  Press and release <kbd>Esc</kbd>, followed by <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd> to go forward or back in word-by-word your remote terminal, respectively.

That said, when a command line I'm working on is complex enough to set right that I need anything more complex than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, I will usually just open it up in my configured `EDITOR` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: when i press `meta+b` and `meta+f` i get  `ƒ` and `∫`, so that doesn't seem to be the right shortcut.

Comment: Meta and Option are two wholly different keys.  Did you try Esc,F and Esc,B?

Comment: i'm on macOS so terminal has this option to send meta using the option key, which i've tried both

Comment: If you're getting ƒ and ∫, that means the Mac is handling its keyboard shortcuts for the Option key before your keystroke is making it to the Terminal program you are using.  Try the Escape-based alternative which does not require the use of Meta.

Comment: no luck, i've tried `Esc+b` `Esc,b` `Esc+f` `Esc,f` `Meta+b` `Option+b` `Meta+f` `Option+f` with that Meta option setting enabled and disabled.

Comment: Are you pressing and releasing Escape, followed by pressing and releasing A/B?  If so, it's possible your remote shell is not using the `readline` library, which means that you likely cannot move word-by-word as you desire.

Comment: The questioner actually did say in the question that this is the Almquist shell, as included in BusyBox.  That does not use Readline.  But it does have word motions in its own line editing library.

Answer (score 0):

As JdeBP said, BusyBox does not use readline. Its key mappings are hardcoded in its `read_key.c` file and interpreted by `lineedit.c`, which means that `~/.inputrc`, `/etc/inputrc`, `termcap` and `terminfo` have no effect. [v1.25](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/read_key.c?h=1_25_stable) hard-codes word-left as `ESC[1;5D` or `ESC[1;3D`, and word-right as `ESC[1;5C` or `ESC[1;3C`, corresponding to obscure xterm variants for mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-arrow/<kbd>Alt</kbd>-arrow. [v1.26](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/read_key.c?h=1_26_stable) added `ESC-b/ESC-f` for backward-word/forward-word, which is usually mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>.

Comment: Please use syntax to improve readability